# Syntax to use group_by() within summarize()

Tags: r, syntax, dplyr, pipe, summarize

How can I use the group_by() function within summarize() as below:

```
summarize(group_by(product),sum(Sales))
```

Comment: But with the following codes I am getting error  data%>%filter(weekdays(date)=Sunday)%>%summarize(group_by(destination),n())
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: Yes I can able to get the answer with above logic, why can't I use as below summarize(group_by(de‌​stination),n())

Comment: `d %>% summarize(group_by(de‌​stination), n())` means `summarize(d, group_by(de‌​stination), n())`, which is different from `summarize(group_by(d, de‌​stination), n())`.

Comment: @cuttlefish isn't `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(n = n())` doing exactly the same. It is better to use `%>%` throughout, skipping the superfluous use of `do` and making full use of the clarity piping (`%.%`) provides.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra; Thanks for your advice !

Comment: @cuttlefish44 no problem. I really like the clean syntax of dplyr and pipes :).

Answer (score 1):

Using pipes is the easiest way, but if you need to find the issue with the current nested form, you need to pass the dataframe of interest (let's say it is **df**) to group_by.

Instead of:

```
summarize(group_by(product),sum(Sales))
```

use:

```
summarize(group_by(df,product),sum(Sales))
```

The first is something like:

```
summarize(group_by(Species), mean(Petal.Length))
```

where iris is missing.

Comment: Beste is to start using pipes, then there is no need to explicitly refer to the data: `df %>% group_by(product) %>% summarize(sales_total = sum(Sales))`.

Comment: Yes. Certainly pipes are the best solution. But I was referring to the missing argument in case one wants to use nested functions.

Comment: Ok, now I see +1.